# Have the fanatic and enthusiast badges been discontinued?

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days

Have the fanatic and enthusiast badges been discontinued?

AFAIK, I've visited at least 30 consecutive days and possibly 100.

For that reason, I wonder whether there is a problem with the badge area or perhaps the fanatic and enthusiast badges have been discontinued?

Comment: You can find your visit history directly on your profile. Click on the number of days you visited and it will open a calendar showing which ones you did and did not visit. You miss a lot of days, and have never hit 30 consecutive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic - latest one awarded today.

Comment: @animuson please see my note to Makoto below.  Thnx

Comment: to those who have voted this down, instead of hit and run down-voting, perhaps you might share your reason(s).

Comment: A real fanatic would never ask such question :P

Answer (score 5):

No, they're very much alive.  Recent activity of both [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) and [Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast) badges indicate that they were awarded within the last hour of this writing.

What you want to do to check/audit this for yourself is to go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249176/gerrylowry). You should see something that looks like this below everything in the right-hand side:

[image]

If the "consecutive" number doesn't have a value greater than 30 or 100, then you're not eligible for those badges.

By clicking on that, you'll be shown a calendar that will show you if there any gaps in days you missed.  Remember:  one day on Stack Overflow is tied to UTC.

Comment: I always look under the "achievement" drop down to see what time SE thinks it is. That's the easiest way.

Comment: @Makoto what constitutes a visit?  i have come to stackoverflow.com everyday AFAIK for a few months however my profile shows big gaping holes.

Comment: @gerryLowry, perhaps you weren't logged in.